# Creating a new column at same time as LEFT JOIN within SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create a table within SQL Server that LEFT JOINS a number of tables together with the required information. Lets call them t1, t2, t3.

With one of the tables, I would like to create a new column in t3 (t3.text2) based off of another column within t3. I've managed to do this really inefficiently by running one query to create a new t3 #temptable by selecting required info and then selecting from that but I presume there is much better way to use a SELECT subquery with CASE WHEN to produce a new column alongside the LEFT JOIN in the overall query, sadly I can't get it working and would welcome any suggestions...

```
SELECT 
    t1.location, t2.name, t3.text1, t3.text2 
FROM 
    t1
LEFT JOIN 
    t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
LEFT JOIN 
    t3 ON t2.b = t3.b
```

Comment: maybe you want something like: (t3.columnx + t3.columny) as text2 in the select?

Comment: can you please describe with real table structure like what you trying to achieve is not clear with t1, t2 and t3. t3.text2 will be new column in select?  or t3 is new temptable you want to create?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT t1.location, t2.name, t3.text1, 
    CASE 
    WHEN t3.some_column = some_value THEN new_value 
    ELSE other_new_value 
    END as text2 

FROM t1
LEFT JOIN t2 ON t1.a = t2.a
LEFT JOIN t3 ON t2.b = t3.b
```

Comment: Thanks @Robert Sievers! Is there a way to do this as a subquery within the LEFT JOIN? This is what I was trying to do so that the select queries look tidy, the 'case when' is a very long list and I wanted to put the conditions alongside the LEFT JOIN.

Comment: You can do LEFT JOIN (SELECT column_name FROM some_table) AS t3 ON t2.b = t3.column_name 

Then replace the column_name with the CASE statement, if that's what you are trying to accomplish.